# jplayerplaylist inside jquery load div

Tags: php, javascript, audio

I am using jplayerplaylist to load a set of mp3's to play.  This works properly if I dedicate a separate page to it with the same code.

However, I can't get this to work using .load() to replace info inside a div.  Basically, I have a page with 3 divs and one of those divs should load the jplayer once it is clicked and replace the content inside said div.  Here's part of the code on the index page.

```
$( "#two" ).one("click",function(){
    $( "#two" ).animate({
            width: "95%"
    }, 1000, "linear", function(){
            $( "#two" ).empty().css({ "background":"none", "height":"auto"}).load( "listen.php");           
    });
```

This should load the code in listen.php and load jplayer.  This works to some extent, but doesn't load the playlist.  All I see is a player with no playlist attached.  The code in listen.php is just straight html laying out the divs for jplayer.  The javascript and php for creating the playlist array is contained in the index page.

The other thing that I can't figure out is if I console.log the array for the playlist, it is reading correctly.  I just can't figure out what the difference is between loading the page on its own or replacing a div in the index page with the listen content.

Any help is much appreciated.  Thanks!